# What does sqlite do when you use group by and don't give it an aggregate function?

Tags: sqlite

It doesn't give an error so what is it supposed to do?

From my experimentation it gives you the last row from the data set.

you do the following:

```
select A, AVG(B), C from table group by C

A
1
2
3
4
```

Then it will say
4 , 4.3 , a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SQL does not allow this.

SQLite (and MySQL) just give the value from some random record in the group.
(It happens to be the last one in this case because of the way the computation is implemented.)

SQLite (beginning with version 3.7.11) guarantees that when you use `MIN` or `MAX`, such unaggregated values come from <strike>the</strike> a record that matches the `MIN`/`MAX`.